# How do I sync data with ADFS?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs4.0

We have Single Sign-On (SSO) done via SAML.

Currently we have requirement to sync users from ADFS to our database as well as ADFS groups.

I was able to google out solutions for LDAP, however that seems quite old.

Is it possible to do this via SAML? Any other method?

I would be using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both SAML and ADFS are about authentication.

What you are referring to is provisioning which is not provided by either.

The modern standard for provisioning is [SCIM](http://www.simplecloud.info/#implementations).

Comment: Thank you, bud. That's exactly hat I have eventually googled out. When it comes to having ADFS, how do one goes about providing SCIM capabilities?

Comment: You wouldn't add it to ADFS. You would something that uses SCIM to access AD.

Comment: So it means AD itself can provide SCIM?

Comment: No - you have to buy or write a SCIM package that is tailored for AD. SCIM is just a set of REST endpoints e.g. "Create User". So you have to have an API that people can call that uses LDAP to write to AD.